# fromIndex < 0: -1

Tags: keycloak, infinispan

I'm getting this wired error message from keycloak. 
I'm running two keycloak instances on the same host, one is fine and the second one is getting me this :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: fromIndex < 0: -1
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at java.util.BitSet.nextClearBit(BitSet.java:744)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.initializer.InitializerState.getNextUnfinishedSegmentFromIndex(InitializerState.java:102)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.initializer.InitializerState.updateLowestUnfinishedSegment(InitializerState.java:98)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.initializer.InitializerState.markSegmentFinished(InitializerState.java:94)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.initializer.InfinispanCacheInitializer.startLoadingImpl(InfinispanCacheInitializer.java:187)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.initializer.InfinispanCacheInitializer.startLoading(InfinispanCacheInitializer.java:108)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.initializer.CacheInitializer.loadSessions(CacheInitializer.java:41)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory$7.run(InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.java:317)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.loadSessionsFromRemoteCache(InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.java:306)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.loadSessionsFromRemoteCaches(InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.java:298)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.access$500(InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.java:68)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory$1.lambda$onEvent$0(InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.java:127)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransactionWithTimeout(KeycloakModelUtils.java:267)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory$1.onEvent(InfinispanUserSessionProviderFactory.java:121)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.services.DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.publish(DefaultKeycloakSessionFactory.java:69)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:170)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]         ... 31 more
Aug 14 17:23:58 keycloak.srv2 sh[2512]: [Server:server-one]
```

I've already lost a bunch of hours trying things around but can't figure out what's wrong 
Any piece of advice would be more than welcome

Comment: Hmmm, what Keycloak and Infinispan server versions are you using? Did you try restarting the Infinispan servers? Maybe there's some partial data there?

Comment: it's keycloak 6 and infinispan 9.4.11, yes already tried to restart infinispan

Comment: So, even after restarting Infinispan you still get this issue? Have you also restarted keycloak? This is a likely a bug anyway, so if you can replicate it I'd get TRACE logging on org.keycloak and org.infinispan and submit it to [Keycloak JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/KEYCLOAK/summary)

Comment: @GalderZamarreño I did try to restart infinispan and keycloak and get the same issue. What is weird is when I tried to start using the jboss-cli, everything works fine. Any chance it's an issue with concurrent starts of keycloaks ?

Comment: I couldn't say. I'd suggest you follow the suggestions I made in the last comment.

Comment: I recently move from 6.0.0 to 7.0.0 and from infinispan 9.4.11 to 9.4.16 and it's now working fine ... weird